# Dúvida sobre herança em Python

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, superclasse

Oi, eu estou estudando POO em Python e vi que dá para herdar os atributos de uma super classe de duas maneiras:

```
Class nome_da_classe(nome_da_superclasse):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(nome_da_superclasse, self, args)
```

**E também assim:**

```
Class nome_da_classe(nome_da_superclasse):
    def __init__(self, args):
        nome_da_superclasse.__init__(self, args)
```

As duas maneiras fazem a mesma coisa ou há alguma diferença entre elas?